# Attributions of $m$ properties to $n$ entities

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Consider $n$ entities $x_i$ that may have $m$ different binary properties $P_j$. There are $2^{n\cdot m}$ ways the properties may be attributed to the entities. For $n = m = 3$ the attribution table may look like this:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
& P_1 & P_2 & P_3 \\ \hline
x_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
x_2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
x_3 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}$$

When we neglect the order of the entities two attribution tables are the same when you get the one from the other by some permutation of the entities (rows). **How many equivalence classes of attributions are there?**

For $n = m = 2$ I found that the number of non-equivalent attributions is

$$a(2,2) = 1 + 2 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 10$$

with $a_0 = a_4 = 1$ being the number of non-equivalent ways to place 0 or 4 entries in the 2x2 table, $a_1 = a_3 = 2$ the number of placing 1 or 3 entries, and $a_2 = 4$ the number of placing 2 entries.

For $n=m=3$, the sum starts and ends the same: $a_0 = a_9 = 1$, $a_1 = a_8 = 3$, but I am already stuck to find $a_2$, i.e. the number of non-equivalent ways to place 2 entries in the 3x3 table. But I guess, it's $9$.

So one might tend to guess that $a(n,n) = 2\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n^2/2\rfloor} n^k$ (for odd $n$), but this number grows way too fast.

So my questions is how $a(n,n)$ or more generally $a(n,m)$ can be systematically derived? Is it a case for generating functions?

---

**Added**: This is the table of $a(n,m)$ for $n,m \leq 5$:

[image]

The diagonal can be found [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=10%2C120%2C3876%2C376992).

---

**Added**: I wonder how many bits you need to represent an equivalence class. Consider $n=m=5$ with 376,992 equivalence classes for which to represent you need at least 19 bits (because $2^{18} =262,144$ and $2^{19} = 524,288$). Being more verbose you need to specify up to five rows, and for each row a number $\leq 5$, the numbers summing up to $5$. So you need $5 \cdot (5 + \lceil \log_2(5)\rceil) = 40$ bits in this representation which gives the essential information.

---

**Added**: The number $a(n,m)$ is also the number of equivalence classes of bipartite $n \times m$ graphs. I could have phrased the question like this as well which would have been much shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many different possible rows are possible?  $2^m$.  Now, apply [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), you have $n$ rows which order doesn't matter for that you wish to have each row assigned to one of the possible values for the row.  $$\binom{n+2^m-1}{2^m-1}$$  In the case of $m=n=2$ this would be $\binom{2+2^2-1}{2^2-1}=\binom{5}{3}=10$

Comment: Thanks for the hint to stars-and-bars, never heard of it before. I searched for the OEIS sequence beginning with $a(2,2), a(3,3), a(4,4), a(5,5)$ according to your formula and found this: https://oeis.org/search?q=10%2C120%2C3876%2C376992. The comment fit perfectly to my question.